# Error: An exception occurred while executing- Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am getting an error when try to execute custom repository:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT COUNT(p0_.id) AS sclr0 FROM PayrollWeek p1_ WITH (NOLOCK), PayrollWeek p0_ WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE p0_.startDate = ? AND p0_.endDate = ?' with params ["startDate", "endDate"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. What I have

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    
    
    $entity = new Payrollperiod();
    
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    
   
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 
            
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        
        $payrollperiod = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')->findOneBy(['startdate'=>$form->get('startDate')->getData(), 'enddate'=>$form->get('endDate')->getData()]);
        
        $payrollweek = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')->findBystartdateAndenddate($form->get('startDate')->getData(), $form->get('endDate')->getData());
        
        $counter = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')->countBystartdateAndenddate('startDate', 'endDate');
      
        if ($counter){
        //If entity exists
        if ($payrollperiod){
                $this->addFlash('error', 'Error: A payroll period is already present with the same start and end date.');
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
            }
            //If PayrollWeek matches the Payrollperiod entered
           elseif ($payrollweek){
            foreach ($payrollweek as $pWeek) {
                $pWeek->setPayrollperiodid($entity); 
                $em->persist($pWeek);
            }
            
          $em->persist($entity);
          $em->flush();
           
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Payroll Period was added.');
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Payroll week was updated.');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
           //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod_show', array('payrollperiodid' => $entity->getpayrollperiodid())));
             }
             else{
               $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll Period does not match a payroll week.');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));  
             }
       }
       
       //return $this->render('comtwclagripayrollBundle::new.html.twig',array('form' => $form->createView()));
       return array(
           'entity' => $entity,
           'form'   => $form->createView(),
       );   
    
        }

}

     public function findBystartdateAndenddate($startdate, $enddate)
    {
                  
       return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('pw')
         ->select('pw')
         ->where ('pw.startdate = :startdate and pw.enddate = :enddate')
        ->setParameter('startdate', $startdate)
        ->setParameter('enddate', $enddate)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    }

   public function countBystartdateAndenddate($startdate, $enddate)
    {
        return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('payrollweek')
         ->select('COUNT(pw)')
         ->from ('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek','pw')
         ->where ('pw.startdate = :startdate and pw.enddate = :enddate')
        ->setParameter('startdate', $startdate)
        ->setParameter('enddate', $enddate)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneorNullResult();
    }
```

I'm trying to count the payroll week to match the payroll period entered. Payroll Period is two weeks while payroll week is one week. For example the user enters Aug 6-Aug19 2017 then it would two records in the payroll table Aug 6-12 & Aug 13-19. Would a count work for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `$form->get('startDate')` and `$form->get('endDate')` try using `$entity->getStartDate()` and `$entity->getEndDate()`, becouse you're passing string instead of `Datetime` object

Comment: ok thanks that fixed the error but it didn't produce the results I wanted